# prove the given inequality (for series )

Tags: sequences-and-series

For any given $n \in \Bbb N,$ prove that, $$1+{1\over 2^3}+\cdots+{1\over n^3} <{3\over 2}.$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that the infinite summation of the series is $1.202...$. That number is less than $1.5 = \frac 32$. (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2Fn%5E3)

Comment: **Hint:** It can be proved by induction that $2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^n {\frac{1}{k^3}}<3-\frac{1}{n^2}.$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way,  for $n> 1$,

$$n^3 > (n-1)n(n+1) \implies \frac1{n^3} < \frac1{(n-1)n(n+1)} \\= \frac12\left[\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n \right) + \left(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1n \right) \right]$$

Using this, its easy to show the LHS $< 1+\frac14< \frac32$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$ is decreasing for every $x>0$ then the following expression holds

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k^3}<\int_0^n\dfrac{1}{x^3}d x$$

Comment: And does that integral converge?

Comment: Yes it does, not starting at 0 but at one. It is easy to see too that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^3} < 1+\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3}$ which solves the problem

Comment: That's why it was a hint :)

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 3$ the sum is less than
$$1+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{(2)(3)}+\frac{1}{(3)(4)}+\frac{1}{(4)(5)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)(n)}\right).$$
Note that $\frac{1}{(2)(3)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{(3)(4)}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{(4)(5)}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}$ and so on. It follows by cancellation (telescoping) that
$$\frac{1}{(2)(3)}+\frac{1}{(3)(4)}+\frac{1}{(4)(5)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)(n)}\lt \frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus our full sum is less than $1+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{6}$.